# Flutter: parsing json response that has multiple keys

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the values of these keys from this json response:

```
{
    "pro": {
        "groups": [
            "1": {
                "name": "Base",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "value": {
                            "raw": "Name",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "value": {
                            "raw": "avatar",
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "Base",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "value": {
                            "raw": "Name",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "value": {
                            "raw": "avatar",
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
    ]
}
}
```

I could get the values "name": "Base"

```
json['pro']['groups']["1"]['name'],
```

But I can't get the values of key "raw".

**How can I get the values of key "raw"?**

Answer (score 0):

The values of `fields` are a list, so you will get a list of `raw` values:

```
List<String> raw = json['pro']['groups']['1']['fields'].map((v) => v['value']['raw'];
```

Also, it seems like groups is an array but as an object? then you can do something like this:

```
List<String> raw = [];
Map<String, dynamic> groups = json['pro']['groups'];
for (var key in groups.keys) {
  raw.add(groups[key]['fields'].map((v) => v['value']['raw']);
}
```

or

```
List<String> raw = groups.keys.map((key) => groups[key]['fields'].map((v) => v['value']['raw']);
```

I haven't tested the code, but hopefully, it works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

first thing first. your json is invalid.
try to [paste your json here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) it will show why is your json is invalid

after you fix the json the new structure json will be looked like this

```
{
  "pro": {
    "groups": [
      {
        "name": "Base",
        "fields": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "value": {
              "raw": "Name",
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "value": {
              "raw": "avatar",
            }
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Base",
        "fields": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "value": {
              "raw": "Name",
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "value": {
              "raw": "avatar",
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and then in order to grab the value of raw, you have to parse the json first using `jsonDecode()`, then you can use something like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> groupOne = json['pro']['groups'][0];
Map<String, dynamic> groupOneFieldOne = groupOne['fields'][0];
print(groupOneFieldOne['value']['raw']);
```

but that's just an example. if you want to access them easily you can use .map() like this:

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> groups = json['pro']['groups'];
  groups.map(
    (Map<String, dynamic> group) => (group['fields'] as List<dynamic>).map(
      (dynamic field) => field['value']['raw'],
    ),
  );
```

that's it! if you want to ask anything just put a comment ;)
you can copy and paste on dartpad

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> groups = json['pro']['groups'];
  print(groups.map(
    (Map<String, dynamic> group) => (group['fields'] as List<dynamic>).map(
      (dynamic field) => field['value']['raw'],
    ),
  ));
}

Map<String, dynamic> json = {
  "pro": {
    "groups": [
      {
        "name": "Base",
        "fields": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "value": {
              "raw": "Name",
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "value": {
              "raw": "avatar",
            }
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Base",
        "fields": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "value": {
              "raw": "Name",
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "value": {
              "raw": "avatar",
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```